# Fixed Points in RSA

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, computer-science, cryptography

I need to prove the following:

For different primes, p and q, there exist, as a consequence of Bezout's Lemma, two natural numbers $a$ and $b$ with $ap - bq = 1$. Prove, if we encrypt $x = ap \bmod n$ (for $n = pq$), than the chiffre is equal to $x$.

How can I do this? I need to show that $D(x,(n,e)) = x^e \bmod n = (ap \bmod pq)^e = \ldots = x$

I have tried using Fermat's Little Theorem (from $x^p \equiv x \pmod p$), and also to show by contradiction: if $x = ap \bmod n$ is not a fixed point then this and that happens, but none of them seemed to help. How cand I solve this?

Thanks in advance :D

Comment: What is chiffre?

Comment: Chiffre or cipher text, they are the same

Comment: what's your definition of a ciphertext?

Comment: x is the plaintext. For RSA: y = D(x,(n,e)) = $x^e\ mod\ n$ is the ciphertext

Answer (score 1):

$x$ is the [unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) integer such that $0\leqslant x<n$, $x\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $x\equiv 1\pmod q$. Since $y=x^e\bmod n$ satisfies $y\equiv 0\pmod p$ and $y\equiv 1\pmod q$ as well, we *must* have $y=x$.

Comment: thanks for  the answer! why are $a_1$ = 0 and $a_2$ = 1?

Comment: p divides ap, so it makes sense a1 = 0, but why is a2 = 1? can t it be just any other number < n?

Comment: @Hsssdksasdkalskmdsma: $ap=1+bq\equiv 1\pmod q$.